# How to import Bootstrap into Vite projects

Tags: vite, react-tsx

How do I correctly import Bootstrap inside a react-ts project opened with Vite? What are the correct commands?

I had this error in the browser after importing the bootstrap in my App.tsx:

[image]

The custom.css file looks like this:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #407BFF
);

$body-bg: #E5E5E5;
$body-color: #263238;

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Answer (score 7):

Try it without the '~' tilde character.

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Comment: or add the ~bootstrap alias to the vite config

Answer (score 0):

this is an excellent tutorial for Bootstrap 4 https://dev.to/kouts/how-to-create-a-vue-js-2-bootstrap-4-project-with-vite-54f1

The process for Bootstrap 5 is more straightforward and you can find it in the official BS5 documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/

Answer (score 0):

I had a project setup with vite + react + swc.

The code from this [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/) worked perfectly to get rid of the error for me. I only used the resolve-alias part in my config.

Valentino also mention it in their comment, so this is just the same answer with a bit more information.

```
const path = require('path')
export default {


root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    hot: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
        refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
        template: {
            transformAssetUrls: {
                base: null,
                includeAbsolute: false,
            },
        },
    }),
    DefineOptions()
],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve('node_modules/bootstrap'),
        'vue$': path.resolve('node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js'),
    }
},
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Without the tilde character, the error was resolved and the page now runs normally.

Is this the only way to import the bootstrap, without the tilde in the code?
On the Vite website (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/), in the 'Setup' topic, some commands are suggested, but I haven't used them, I still don't know how to open a project correctly using those commands.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).